# Acrobat DC Two Check boxes on or the other must be checked

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I have two checkboxes one named OPEN the other named WOMEN.  I would like to require that one or the other has to be checked.  If one isn't checked then both boxes would show as required.  As soon as you check a box the other requirement goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by doing the following.

On "OPEN" Button

```
if (this.getField("OPEN").value != "Yes") {
this.getField("WOMEN").required = true ;
this.getField("OPEN").required = true ;
} else {
this.getField("WOMEN").required = false ;
this.getField("WOMEN").value="Off";
}
```

On "WOMEN" Button

```
if (this.getField("WOMEN").value != "Yes") {
this.getField("OPEN").required = true ;
this.getField("WOMEN").required = true ;
} else {
this.getField("OPEN").required = false ;
this.getField("OPEN").value="Off";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you wanting to check these fields? This should help get you started. Place this code on a button under the run a script mouse up. When the button is clicked the code will execute.

```
// Assign a variable to each check box  
var openCheck = getField("OPEN");
var womenCheck = getField("WOMEN");

// If neither box is checked when the button is clicked 
if (openCheck.value == "Off" && womenCheck.value == "Off") {
    // Alert that they are required fields
    app.alert("These fields are required");
}

// If OPEN is checked, uncheck WOMEN
if (openCheck.value == "On") {
    womenCheck.value = "Off";
}

// If WOMEN is checked, uncheck OPEN
if (womenCheck.value == "On") {
    openCheck.value = "Off";
}
```